# New Window Doesn't Load

Tags: java, wait

I need some help, I have a method which is performed when a button is clicked, this method then opens a new window that updates a variable in another class, the method then gets this variable from the class and then uses it.

The window that is loaded is blank, and it seems as if the wait() function is causing the thread to cease before the new window is loaded.

```
private void autoFillUsersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    publicLesson pL= new publicLesson();
    new dateSelect().setVisible(true);
    try{
        synchronized(this){
            this.wait();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
  int var= pL.getAmount();
  System.out.println("var ="+var);

    DefaultTableModel defaultModel = (DefaultTableModel) pupilTable.getModel();
    for (int i = 0; i <= (userCountAmount - 1); i++) {
        defaultModel.setValueAt(var, 5, i);
        System.out.println("BeingSet");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is anything ever `notify()`ing the Object that is calling `this.wait()`?

Comment: Swing has only one thread! So wait is monopolizing that only thread, so new window will never be created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking the [*Event Dispatch Thread*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). By not allowing the EDT to move past the `wait` call, no events can be processed which means nothing can be painted.

Instead of using a new window, try using a [modal dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html). Modal dialogs block all access to other top level components (depending on the modality type) until they are properly disposed of.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed. Waiting on the event dispatch thread makes it block completely, and thus prevents any repaint to happen. So the EDT can't paint anything anymore while you're waiting.

Long-running tasks, and even more blocking tasks, should not be done in the event dispatch thread. It's not clear at all why you're using `wait()` here, BTW.

And catching Exception and ignoring it completely is one of the worst things you could do.

Comment: Sorry, let me clear this up, i need the program to wait for input in the other window, before obtaining the variables from pL.getAmount()

Comment: That's what a modal dialog does. Use that. Or if it's not an option, register an event listener on the other window, and make it trigger an event once the variable is ready to be consumed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that way, because Swing runs on one thread only! You need to move the processing you are doing after wait, into that window you are creating. You cannot depend on wait.

Here is a good document to read:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=153

Answer (score 0):

wait method is inherited from Object() and [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) state

> Causes current thread to wait until another thread invokes the
>   notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object. In other
>   words, this method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the call
>   wait(0).

Hence, you must give it something to wait for, but as you are blocking the only thread, there's no way it paints something in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Is it your aim to wait in your main JFrame until the User entered the data you need in another JFrame ? 
if thats your aim just have a look at Dialog ModalityTypes.

http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html

When constructing the new Dialog just give the parent dialog as a prameter to the constructor and then call

```
super(parentDialog, Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
```

then your main JFrame will wait for your new JDialog to close until it runs the rest of the function.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with some answers: remove the try/catch/synchronized block and use javax.swing.JDialog to receive the user input.
Refer to the official Swing documentation, it provides good enough examples, 
i.e. this one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html regarding the JDialog.